# Create object from type in dart / flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to create an object from type in dart?
Example of what I want to do but it is not working:

```
// select the button type based on certain value (valid in this case)
final button = valid ? ElevatedButton : OutlinedButton;
```

```
// create the correct button
button(....) // this does not work
```

Is there a way to make this work?

I don't want to have code that looks like this because there will be duplications:

```
    if (valid) {
      return OutlinedButton(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            SvgPicture.asset(image, width: 24.0),
            Text(label),
            Opacity(opacity: 0, child: SvgPicture.asset(image, width: 24.0)),
          ],
        ),
        onPressed: () async => await updatePassword(
          context: context,
          ref: ref,
          newPassword: ref.read(updatePasswordControllerProvider).newPassword,
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return ElevatedButton(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            SvgPicture.asset(image, width: 24.0),
            Text(label),
            Opacity(opacity: 0, child: SvgPicture.asset(image, width: 24.0)),
          ],
        ),
        onPressed: null,
      );
    }
```

Comment: Instead of using a `Type`, use a *callback* that constructs the type you want. `var makeButton = valid ? ElevatedButton.new : OutlinedButton.new; var button = makeButton(...);`

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that as these types don't have same properties. Also the parent class of these types is not a concrete class which could you have used.

In Flutter, you can do:

```dart
final button = valid ? ElevatedButton(...) : OutlinedButton(...);
```

---

#### Update:

Why don't you just refactor duplicated `Row` in a getter like this:

```dart
Row get row => Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    SvgPicture.asset(image, width: 24.0),
    Text(label),
    Opacity(opacity: 0, child: SvgPicture.asset(image, width: 24.0)),
  ],
);
```

After this you can use:

```dart
if (valid) {
  return OutlinedButton(
    child: row,
    onPressed: () async => await updatePassword(
      context: context,
      ref: ref,
      newPassword: ref.read(updatePasswordControllerProvider).newPassword,
    ),
  );
} else {
  return ElevatedButton(
    child: row,
    onPressed: null,
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am aware of the solution you mentioned.  I am trying to avoid it since I will end up with lots of duplicate code when creating the objects.

Comment: Even if you could have done `button(...)`, you still had to provide those properties like `onPressed`, `child`. Won't that be a duplication? Because all I am saying is to replace your `button` with `Elevated/Outlined` `button`. To prevent such duplications I'll suggest you create a separate class, but for that I need to know what exact properties you're adding in your button.

Comment: I have updated my post.  The Row is duplicated.  I know that it is possible to reduce the duplication but it will not be easy especially if you have lots of duplicates.